# Time Dilation And Comparing Inertial And Non Inertial Reference Frames

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, rotational-dynamics, acceleration, time-dilation

Can we calculate the total observed time dilation on a spaceship and a planet by combining the planet's relativistic spin velocity and the spaceship's approach or recession velocity from the planet it came from and where it's heading? Would the spaceship see both planets as time-dilated due to their combined relativistic spin and approach/recession velocities? Should we consider both the spin velocity and the apparent recession/approach velocity, or just one of them, in such calculations?

Comment: Technically yes, you would have to take the speed of the planets' spinning surfaces into account when calculating time dilation. For any realistic scenario though this is negligible compared to the speed of the rocket.

Comment: For reference, the Earth's surface is moving about 0.46 km/s relative to its center; the effects of gravitational time dilation at the surface of the Earth relative to an observer in distant space is the same as time dilation due to 11 km/s (Earth's escape velocity); relativistic rocket, by contrast, would move at thousands of km/s.

Answer (score 0):

Total time dilation factor is the time dilation factor caused by the spin motion, measured in the frame where the spinning thing has no linear motion, multiplied by the time dilation factor caused by the linear motion of the spinning thing.

I that is unclear, you just multiply the time dilation factors.

Here total time dilation factor means how much delay a clock on the surface of the spinning and linearly moving thing accumulates during a full rotation, compared to a clock that has no spin motion and no linear motion.